# Complicated inner join in Spark or Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have table X with `key(a,b)` and table `Y` with `key(a)`. I searched over multiple API functions in Spark but can not find something that can give me a join of both these table by only `key(a)`.

Have two Data structures (think of them as two tables with two different keys)

```
X.take(1) -> made of key(a,b)

[((u'"1"', u'"B8"'), (u'"1"', u'"B8"', array([[  7.16677290e-01,   4.15236265e-01,   7.02316511e-02]])))]

Y.take(1) -> have key(a)

[(u'"5"', (u'"5"', array([[ 0.86596322,  0.29811589,  0.29083844,  0.51458565,  0.23767414]])))]
```

Now, I want a structure something like `a -> [a,b,array_1,array_2]`.

Cogroup didn't serve my purpose as it returns a cartesian product of `key(a,b)` and `key(a)`.

Any suggestions or hints on how can I get a data structure with rows like:

`a -> [a,b,array_1,array_2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you have to keep the key as `(a,b)` throughout the entire join?  Seems like you could change the structure of your RDD slightly to make the join work.

Just change `((a,b),[value])` to `(a,(b,[value]))`, then join with `(a,[value])`.  You'll end up with `(a, Iterable((b,[value])), Iterable([value])`.

Comment: I could do change in keys, but I dont want to do that. It is not closer to [a,b,[value1], value2].

Comment: Yes it is.  You can map `(a, Iterable((b,[value])), Iterable([value])` to `(a, (a,b,[value1],[value2]))` quite easily.